# How to set up file download that requires authentication in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

Do I have to create an API for token authentication or is there another way I can create some kind of login that would allow me to download a .csv file?  I need a status code of 200 on successful authentication, otherwise the request should return a 401 status code and the file should not be downloaded. Does anyone have any advice on how I can achieve this? Ideally it should be as simple as possible to implement.

Comment: Do you already have a website? What have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: I do have a website up on IIS, I just need a suggestion on where to start.

Comment: Very broad question, to broad for a single answer here.  What are you going to use for authentication?  Identity, SSO (Google/Facebook etc) or other?

Comment: Whatever authentication (Windows/token based/other) you choose, there is a corresponding way to protect downloads. So before you asked about "how to", that decision must come first, or this question isn't specific enough and not suitable for Stack Overflow format. This is not a site for broad tutorials/discussions.

Answer (score -1):

I have two suggestions about this.

- You can put all download resources in the same folder, and the folder
  will have a url pointing to it whether it is inside the application
  or as an independent application. In the structure tree on the left
  side of IISManager. As long as you select the folder and enable
  authentication and disable Anonymous Authentication in the
  Authentication module, any request to access the folder will be
  required to verify identity.

[image]

- WIthout setting on IIS, you can use filters of Web Api.
  [Authentication filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) let you set an authentication scheme for
  individual controllers or actions.

  ```
  [Authorize] // Require authenticated requests.
  public class HomeController : ApiController
  {
       public IHttpActionResult Get() { . . . }

       [IdentityBasicAuthentication] // Enable Basic authentication for this action.
       public IHttpActionResult Post() { . . . }
  }
  ```